# Is there an alternative to Combine's @Published that signals a value change after it has taken place instead of before?

Tags: swift, combine

I would like to use Combine's [`@Published`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) attribute to respond to changes in a property, but it seems that it signals before the change to the property has taken place, like a `willSet` observer. The following code:

```
import Combine

class A {
    @Published var foo = false
}

let a = A()
let fooSink = a.$foo.dropFirst().sink { _ in // `dropFirst()` is to ignore the initial value
    print("foo is now \(a.foo)")
}

a.foo = true
```

outputs:

> foo is now false

I'd like the sink to run after the property has changed like a `didSet` observer so that `foo` would be true at that point. Is there an alternative publisher that signals then, or a way of making `@Published` work like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write your own custom property wrapper:

```
import Combine


@propertyWrapper
class DidSet<Value> {
    private var val: Value
    private let subject: CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>

    init(wrappedValue value: Value) {
        val = value
        subject = CurrentValueSubject(value)
        wrappedValue = value
    }

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        set {
            val = newValue
            subject.send(val)
        }
        get { val }
    }

    public var projectedValue: CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never> {
      get { subject }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this really need to use a `CurrentValueSubject`? It looks to me like the CurrentValueSubject will always have the same value as the `wrappedValue` property.  Why not use `PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>`, just like the `objectWillChange`?

Comment: Both are fine. CurrentValueSubject is a little bit more universal as a generic solution.

Answer (score 14):

There is a thread on the Swift forums for this issue. Reasons of why they made the decision to fire signals on "willSet" and not "didSet" explained by **Tony_Parker**

> We (and SwiftUI) chose willChange because it has some advantages over
> didChange:
>
> - It enables snapshotting the state of the object (since you
>   have access to both the old and new value, via the current value of
>   the property and the value you receive). This is important for
>   SwiftUI's performance, but has other applications.
> - "will" notifications are easier to coalesce at a low level, because you can
>   skip further notifications until some other event (e.g., a run loop
>   spin). Combine makes this coalescing straightforward with operators
>   like removeDuplicates, although I do think we need a few more grouping
>   operators to help with things like run loop integration.
> - It's easier to make the mistake of getting a half-modified object with did,
>   because one change is finished but another may not be done yet.

I do not intuitively understand that I'm getting willSend event instead of didSet, when I receive a value. It does not seem like a convenient solution for me. For example, what do you do, when in ViewController you receiving a "new items event" from ViewModel, and should reload your table/collection? In table view's `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` methods you can't access new items with `self.viewModel.item[x]` because it's not set yet. In this case, you have to create a redundant state variable just for the caching of the new values within `receiveValue:` block.

Maybe it's good for SwiftUI inner mechanisms, but IMHO, not so obvious and convenient for other usecases.

User **clayellis** in the thread above proposed solution which I'm using:

Publisher+didSet.swift

```
extension Published.Publisher {
    var didSet: AnyPublisher<Value, Never> {
        self.receive(on: RunLoop.main).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Now I can use it like this and get didSet value:

```
    self.viewModel.$items.didSet.sink { [weak self] (models) in
        self?.updateData()
    }.store(in: &self.subscriptions)
```

I'm not sure if it is stable for future Combine updates, though.

UPD: Worth to mention that it can possibly cause bugs (races) if you set value from a different thread than the main.

Original topic link: https://forums.swift.org/t/is-this-a-bug-in-published/31292/37?page=2

Answer (score 8):

Further to Eluss's good explanation, I'll add some code that works. You need to create your own `PassthroughSubject` to make a publisher, and use the property observer `didSet` to send changes *after* the change has taken place.

```
import Combine

class A {
    public var fooDidChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var foo = false { didSet { fooDidChange.send() } }
}

let a = A()
let fooSink = a.fooDidChange.sink { _ in
    print("foo is now \(a.foo)")
}

a.foo = true
```

Comment: Thank you, that’s exactly what I ended up doing. Presumably it would possible to encapsulate that pattern in a custom property wrapper (perhaps using a custom publisher, but perhaps it could be done using a PassthroughSubject).

Comment: Great, I understand that and have used instead of @Publish

Answer (score 7):

Before the introduction of `ObservableObject` SwiftUI used to work the way that you specify - it would notify you after the change has been made. The change to `willChange` was made intentionally and is probably caused by some optimizations, so using `ObservableObjsect` with `@Published` will always notify you before the changed by design. Of course you could decide not to use the `@Published` property wrapper and implement the notifications yourself in a `didChange` callback and send them via `objectWillChange` property, but this would be against the convention and might cause issues with updating views. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject/3362556-objectwillchange) and it's done automatically when used with `@Published`.
If you need the sink for something else than ui updates, then I would implement another publisher and not go agains the `ObservableObject` convention.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to just use a `CurrentValueSubject` instead of a member variable with the `@Published` attribute. So for example, the following:

```
@Published public var foo: Int = 10
```

would become:

```
public let foo: CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never> = CurrentValueSubject(10)
```

This obviously has some disadvantages, not least of which is that you need to access the value as `object.foo.value` instead of just `object.foo`. It does give you the behavior you're looking for, however.